# Sort List of List and maintain correct number of lists in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

For the following code...

```
var lightningFileNames = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LightningFileNames"];
var files = Directory.GetFiles(mapPath, lightningFileNames);

List<List<LightningStrikeModel>> ltgStrikes = new List<List<LightningStrikeModel>>();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    var stringData = new List<string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var data = reader.ReadLine().Trim();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                stringData.Add(data);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    //extracted from file name to get an orderby
    int lgtTemp = int.Parse(Regex.Match(file, @"\d+").Value);

    ltgStrikes.Add((from item in stringData
                    select item.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    into rawData
                    where rawData.Length >= 4
                    select new LightningStrikeModel
                    {
                        Date = rawData[0],
                        Time = rawData[1],
                        Latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(rawData[2]),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(rawData[3]),
                        Polarity = Convert.ToDecimal(rawData[4]),
                        orderBy = lgtTemp
                    }).ToList());

}
var tempLtg = ltgStrikes
        .SelectMany(record => record)
        .OrderBy(record => record.orderBy)
        .GroupBy(record => record.orderBy).ToList();

return ltgStrikes;
```

With filenames of ltg_1.txt, ltg_2.txt ... ltg_12.txt

My problem exists because of 3 things.

1) because I am going out to a folder location to grab a list of files to read the data and populate a list, I get them in the order they are in the folder - so I would read the files in this order

> _1.txt, _10.txt, _11.txt, _12.txt, _2.txt and so on

I am unable to change the files names.

2) Some of the files will have nothing in them -  a blank file.  But I still need to 'read it' and add a place holder to my List> ltgStrikes - i essentially need to have a list of 12 lists regardless of data.

3) Currently, I can achieve a list of 12 lists regardless of data but they are in the wrong order because its adding them to the ltgStrikes in the order they are read. so

> _1.txt has an index of [0], _10.txt has an index of [1] but in the end result, it should have an index of [9], _5.txt has an index of [8] but should be [4]

I have tried something like the following but because some files are empty, I do not get a list of 12 lists.  my current data only gives me a list of 2 lists since only 2 files of data in them.

```
var tempLtg = ltgStrikes
                .SelectMany(record => record)
                .OrderBy(record => record.orderBy)
                .GroupBy(record => record.orderBy).ToList();
```

What am I not seeing?  FYI - orderBy is not used to order the data here but ultimately it can be.  I need it in another part of the application

Comment: You might want to consider using `File.ReadLines` as a way to get an `IEnumerable<string>` you can use to read the lines of the file and avoid an intermediate collection before using it in your query.

Comment: File.ReadLines() + If youre adamant about your 12x12 I would create a static `LightningStrikeModel.EmptyModel = new LightningStrikeModel()` and supply that if a whole file has no content. You can then check against it (aka `string.Empty`, `int MinValue` etc. ) - that way you have at least one Model per file.

Comment: Could you try sorting the files by `DateCreated` or `DateModified`?

Comment: This question is very complicated and unclear. I think the question you are asking is *how do I sort a list of files into natural order instead of ordinal order*?  **Is that the question?** If it is, then this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp and should be closed.

Comment: @EricLippert - you made my question much clearer and for my learning I did try what you had suggested from a duplicate question and agree it should be closed.

Comment: I notice that you check to see if the length is `>= 4` but then you dereference `[4]`. You should be checking for `>4` or `>=5`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a whole pile of problems here because you're doing stuff in the wrong order.  If you're mixing loops with LINQ like this, odds are good the whole thing will be much better if you just make the whole thing into one big query with no loops. Let's do that:

```
return Directory.GetFiles(mapPath, lightningFileNames)
  .InNaturalOrder() // You write this!
```

OK, now we have a sequence of files in the right order.  What do we want next?  The contents of the files, trimmed.

```
  .Select(f => File.ReadLines(f)
    .Select(l => l.Trim())
    .Where(l => l != ""))
```

OK, now we have a sequence of sequences of strings. What do we want? A list of lists of LightningStrikeModels. So we transform each string into a model. That gives us a sequence of models.

```
  .Select (stringData =>
    (from item in stringData
    select item.Split(new[] { ' ' },
      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    into rawData
    where rawData.Length >= 5
    select new LightningStrikeModel (...))
```

We transform each sequence of models into a list of models.

```
    .ToList())
```

We now have a sequence of lists of models. We want a list of lists of models:

```
  .ToList();
```

And we're done. We have a list of lists of models, and we can return it.

But let's not stop there. **When you're done writing the code ask yourself if you could have done better.**

If we do that then we immediately see that the Trim and the filter of empty strings is completely unnecessary. Why? Because we're going to take that string, split it on spaces, eliminate the empty substrings, and discard any string that had fewer than four substrings between spaces. So why did we bother to trim the leading and trailing spaces, and eliminate empty entries? The split would do the former, and the check to see if there are four substrings does the latter.  So we can make this simpler:

```
return Directory.GetFiles(mapPath, lightningFileNames)
  .InNaturalOrder()
  .Select(f => File.ReadLines(f))
  .Select (stringData =>
  ...
```

Now *do it again*.  Can we make *this* simpler? Yes. We have two selects in a row, so we can merge them.

```
return Directory.GetFiles(mapPath, lightningFileNames)
  .InNaturalOrder()
  .Select (f =>
    (from item in File.ReadLines(f)
    select item.Split(new[] { ' ' },
      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    into rawData
    where rawData.Length >= 5
    select new LightningStrikeModel (...))
```

Can we make this better?  OH YES WE CAN.  We can make two things: a splitter helper and a factory.

```
static string[] SpaceSplit(this string s) => s.Split( ... );

static LightningStrikeModel BuildModel(this string[] parts) => new ...
```

And now our query is

```
return Directory.GetFiles(mapPath, lightningFileNames)
  .InNaturalOrder()
  .Select (f =>
    File.ReadLines(f)
      .Select(line => line.SpaceSplit())
      .Where(rawData => rawData.Length >= 5)
      .Select(rawData => rawData.BuildModel())
      .ToList())
  .ToList();
```

OMG look at how much shorter and cleaner that solution is compared to the mess we started with.  Look at how clearly correct it is.  And easy to understand and maintain.  **Always be asking yourself if you can make it better**.

Can we make this solution better?  Yes we can!  We can notice for example that we do no error checking on whether or not the strings convert cleanly to decimals. What if they don't? That error should probably be handled somehow, but right now it is not.  Think about how you might solve that in a manner that does not make the call site harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the files in order, you could order `files` in the foreach

```
foreach(string file in files.OrderBy(x=>int.Parse(Regex.Match(x,@"(\d+)\.txt").Groups[1].Value))){
```

Comment: While @EricLippert gave me the most appropriate solution to what I needed I feel this suggestion was a much simpler solution.  I was already in the process of looking at sorting the initial file list when i saw you had posted this.